# Does SPF Validate Reply-To and Bounce-To e-mails?

Tags: email, smtp, spf

I couldn't find it in the official documentation so I ask it here.

Does SPF also validate the other e-mail configurations like "Reply-To" besides the "From" e-mail?

The situation is as follows:
I send an e-mail from my server with a valid "From" e-mail for my server.

Is it possible to include in "Reply-To" and "Bounce-To" e-mails for which my server is not authorized to send e-mails?

Tks,
ED

Answer (score 2):

SPF does not validate any address in any of the mail headers. It only validates the reverse-path in the SMTP envelope (and optionally the client host address supplied in the SMTP HELO command, but that is not related to your question), which may or may not be the same as the From address. So yes, you can include any address in the Reply-To etc. headers. Actually you can use any From address, even addresses completely unrelated to your domain, as long as you assure that your mail client library does not specify that address as the reverse-path.

Comment: This is also described in more detail here: http://www.openspf.org/Best_Practices/Webgenerated

Comment: The correct link is http://www.open-spf.org/Best_Practices/Webgenerated/