# Does the SPF record check take care about the Sender header?

Tags: email, spf

I'm just wondering if the `Sender:` header is read when doing an SPF record check.

So, when a mail server receives an e-mail that contains a `Sender:` header that differs from the `From:` header, which one is used by the receiving server to check if the mail has been sent from the right mail server?

If I understand this right, SPF only checks the `MAIL FROM` command from SMTP (?) which is the equivalent to the e-mail `From:` header (?) and therefore the `Sender:` header is never taken into account...?

- http://www.openspf.org/svn/project/specs/rfc4408.txt

Is this right?

So, let's dig a bit deeper and think about a web form that sends out an email. When filling out this form, one can enter his own e-mail address so that any reply to this mail is sent to the person who filled out the form, and not to the server. Yes, there's the `Reply-To:` header, but when reading the RFC 4021 and 2822 I thought that it should also be allowed to send the server's address with the `Sender:` header and the users address with the `From:` header.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-3.6.2
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.2

Any expert who can correct me or confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I understand this right, SPF only checks the MAIL FROM command from SMTP (?) **which is the equivalent to the e-mail From: header (?)** and therefore the Sender: header is never taken into account...?

The bold statement above was just plainly wrong. [SPF doesn't care about message header at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21627115/3604386). In fact, the remote server can reject the email because of SPF without looking at email header and body.

Comment: This is correct, but would benefit from a brief discussion of envelope vs headers.